# Can the Warlock kill a player who has the Veil of Shadows?

Tags: werewolv.es

As the Veil of Shadows hides a player's witchcraft use as to be shown as innocent to the Witch Hunter, would this allow the Warlock to kill the player even if he actually uses witchcraft?

Answer (score 2):

I had to dig into the code to check for this, because it's an unintended interaction, but the short answer is yes - a Warlock can kill a Seer (or whatever) that has a Veil of Shadows.

In addition, a Warlock keeps record of players that they have visited before, and whether their visit results in a kill depends on them having previously viewed them as a Witchcraft user. This means that a Warlock could visit a Seer wearing a Veil, check them as a non-wc user. The Seer could then subsequently have their Veil stolen but the Warlock would still be able to kill them.